# Selenium request on nike

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, nike

Here is my code. I wanted to hypothetically request this shoe size on the nike website using selenium. However my code gets this error before it can find the size:

Error:
We had an issue with your request. If you continue experiencing issues, try refreshing the page.

[ Code: 74914217 ]

I would appreciate your help in this matter:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

chromedriver_path = "/Users/shaheersaud/Downloads/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)

driver.get("https://www.nike.com/t/air-jordan-2-retro-mens-shoes-F577Gc/DR8884-001")

try:
    SizeInput = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "13"))
        
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Cannot find: {e}")
SizeInput.click()
```

I tried using the Xpath and class but it still did not work, same error happens